# C++ match string in file and get line number

Tags: c++, iostream, string-matching

I have a file with the top 1000 baby names.  I want to ask the user for a name...search the file...and tell the user what rank that name is for boy names and what rank for girl names. If it isn't in boy names or girl names, it tells the user it's not among the popular names for that gender.

The file is laid out like this:

```
Rank Boy-Names Girl-Names
1    Jacob     Emily
2    Michael   Emma
.
.
.
```

Desired output for input `Michael` would be:

> Michael is 2nd most popular among boy names.

If Michael is not in girl names it should say:

> Michael is not among the most popular girl names

Though if it was, it would say:

> Micheal is (rank) among girl names

The code I have so far is below.. I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks for any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
void find_name(string name);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string name;
    cout << "Please enter a baby name to search for:\n";
    cin >> name;
    /*while(!(cin>>name))
    {
        cout << "Please enter a baby name to search for:\n";
        cin >> name;
    }*/
    find_name(name);

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void find_name(string name)
{
    ifstream input;
    int line = 0;
    string line1 = " ";
    int rank;
    string boy_name = "";
    string girl_name = "";
    input.open("/<path>/babynames2004.rtf");
    if (!input)
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    while(input.good())
    {
        while(getline(input,line1))
        {
            input >> rank >> boy_name >> girl_name;
            if (boy_name == name)
            {
                cout << name << " is ranked " << rank << " among boy names\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << name << " is not among the popular boy names\n";
            }
            if (girl_name == name)
            {
                cout << name << " is ranked " << rank << " among girl names\n"; 
            }
            else
            {
                cout << name << " is not among the popular girl names\n";
            }
        }
    }
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: Is this code not working? How does it fail? What does it do? What is your question?

Comment: Well it just always outputs: <name> is not among popular boy names. and then on the next line says <name> is not among popular girl names.

Comment: Well, is the name you enter in the file? If not then the output is what I expect from your code...

Comment: Not related to your question, but in C++ you usually declare variables just before their use, not all at the top of a function.

Comment: you are simply looping over all the lines in the files, what is the problem?

Comment: Well I picked a name that is for sure in the list to see if it would print the correct rank etc. But no matter what name I entered it would say it wasn't among the popular names for boys or girls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, looks like you're trying to open a rich text format file (.rtf). This won't work, as the file doesn't contains only text but also other data (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format).

Then in your code: `while(getline(input,line1))` reads a line every iteration. That's fine, but inside the loop yo do `input >> rank >> boy_name >> girl_name;` which continues to read in next line

You want to work with `line1`. You can construct a stringstream from line1, then read the names from it:

```
stringstream ss(line1):
ss >> rank >> boy_name >> girl_name;
```

That and what Beta wrote in his answer; you "give up" in each line where names don't match.

Answer (score 3):

You are conceding defeat ("X is not among the popular Y names") before you have finished scanning the list. A good simple way (if not the most efficient) is to remember the ranks until the end of the list, before announcing that there was no match. Something like this:

```
bool boyrank = false, girlrank = false;

while(getline(input,line1))
{
  input >> rank >> boy_name >> girl_name;
  if (boy_name == name)
    {
      cout << name << " is ranked " << rank << " among boy names\n";
      boyrank = true;
    }

  if (girl_name == name)
    {
      cout << name << " is ranked " << rank << " among girl names\n";
      girlrank = true;
    }
}

if(boyrank == false)
{
  cout << name << " is not among the popular boy names\n";
}
if(girlrank == false)
{
  cout << name << " is not among the popular girl names\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely do some more analysis and isolation of your problem before posting a question.

For instance, you are in a loop calling `getline`, which reads a line of text into `line1` out of your `input`.  But then you do nothing with `line1`.  You use iostream operators to read in the fields of data on the line after it.  So this is going to effectively skip every other line.  It would be easy to tell that if you just put in a debugging sanity check in your loop like:

```
cout << "rank = " << rank << " boy_name = " << boy_name << 
        " girl_name = " << girl_name << endl;
```

Then you could formulate your question as "why am I only getting every other line".  Which would be easier for people to answer, but you might also have a chance at answering it yourself.

Another potential problem is if you have a .RTF "Rich Text" file instead of a plain-ol text file.  It may have extra junk in it that's confusing your code.  Homework assignments would not typically give you wacky formats to deal with, because that's a whole new can of worms.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But you don't have to say I need to do more analysis etc before posting a question. I have been looking over results from searched in Google for 3 hours and plus I am probably not nearly as good at understanding what everything in C++ does/means in context.

Comment: You're welcome.  But you're going to have to trust me that on StackOverflow (and programming help communities in general) people want you to indicate a more precise point where your comprehension goes from "okay, I understand THIS" to "however, I don't understand THAT".  It's much better than pasting code and saying "It doesn't do what I want" without explaining what it *did* do...and what sorts of things you've tried in response.  See also: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/