# Reading A .txt file into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ match string in file and get line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779469/c-match-string-in-file-and-get-line-number)

I have been given a HW assignment so I am not asking for a full set of code but maybe some hints at what I am suppose to do. The assignment is as follows:
The text file babynames2004.txt is included. Contains a list of the 1000 most popular names in the US. 
It is a space-delimited file of 1000 entries in which the rank is listed first, followed by the corresponding boy name and girl name. The most popular names are listed first and the least popular names are listed last. write a program that allows the user to input a name. The program should then read from the file and search for a matching name among the girls and boys then store this information in an array. If a match is found, it should output the rank of the name. The program should also indicate if there is no match.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
//function prototypes
void input(int search(const int name[][Max_Girl_Name], int, int, int );
void display(


int main()
{
  const int Max_Girl_Name = 1000, Max_Boy_Name = 1000;     //array sizes
  int name[][Max_Girl_Name], count(0);

  ifstream inputfile; //open stored file
  inputFile.open("c:/temp/babynames2004.txt")
  if (inputFile.fail())
  {
     cout<<"Error opening File\n";
  }
  else 
  {
     while(!inputFile.eof())
     inputFile>>name[count];
     count++
  }

  input(
  searchname = (
  display(

  inputFile.close();

  cout << count " is ranked " << Rank <<  

}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

int search(const int name[][Max_Girl_Name], int name_input, int targetname, int size_Dimension_1)
{
  for(int i = 0;i<size_Dimension_1;i++)
  {
    int index = 0;
    bool found = false;
    while ((!found) && (index < number_used))
      if (target == name[index])
         found = true
      else 
           index++;

      if(found)
               return index;
      else -1;
    }
}
```

I also have a couple of thoughts:

1. Would this be solved using a multidimensional array, and would they be for example `names[boy_name][girl_name]`?
2. Would the functions the this program be the `search(value)`, `input(void)`, `output(void)`?
3. how would you go about iterating through both indices of the array?

I hope I am clear enough.

Comment: @irrelephant Nope. not even *close*.

Comment: No, this is just how far I have gotten. I am having trouble figuring out what types of functions I would use for this program.

Comment: There are a lot of syntax errors. I suggest using a free IDE like Visual Studio Express, if you aren't doing that already.

Comment: Do you familiar with STL? Does associative container map make sense for you? File i/o can be done in various ways, as C++ is object oreinted language have you considered object i/o?(for ex. using iostream_iterator). Also interesting to know what knowledge you need confirm by your assignement.

Comment: We have not reached objects yet, I just learned about I/O and were moving into arrays right now.

Comment: Take a look on a std::map. This will make your implementation way much easier!

Comment: @besworland it's probably better that he figures out the hard way to do it first, shortcuts too early can be bad.

Comment: @lan WHat do you mean? I was not offensive, at all:)

Comment: If you watch these homework questions long enough, you remember them...if I were a teacher, I'd at least mix up the exercises a bit from term to term.  "1000 baby names C++" will find this on SO search.  [C++ match string in file and get line number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779469/c-match-string-in-file-and-get-line-number)

Comment: @HostileFork I've not been here too long and yet the lack of variety has already struck me TBH - I get the feeling the lecturers are perhaps busy doing more interesting stuff...

Answer (score 1):

According to your level of knowledge, you are stuck to arrays. You should have 3 onedimensional arrays, like you already defined. (In real program you would define a class containing the three items boysname, girlsname and rank)

1.should be something like that:

```
int maxLines=1000;
int maNameLength=100; // This would go away later coz you would use std::string when you learnt them
char boysName[maxLines][maxNameLength];
char girlsName[maxLines][maxNameLength];
int rank[maxLines];
```

(so here goes your "multidimensional array", thats the girls and boys names)

2.you are right, 3 functions like that would do. The input-function should e.g. read the file line by line, split it up into the three fields and store them in these arrays. This can be done in various ways, using high-level constructs from std:: library, or as a beginner maybe you want to do it manually. (Watch out for file having more lines than your array size, or names being longer than maxNameLength). The search-function should go thru your array and check for name-equalness, and return the array index if found, otherwise e.g. -1

the output-function then takes this array-index, checks first wether its valid (>=0 and lt maxLines), then output either the rank or not found).

Dont get frustrated, you have lots of work to do as a beginner to get this program up and running...

Answer (score 1):

Before some hints, just a suggestion for how to approach things. until coding becomes like a second nature to you, you should spend time writing out in pseduocode what you want your final code to do. Then change the lines into comments and begin to flesh out the variables and loops etc that you need to fulfil the requirements. By doing that (a) you become more methodical, and (b) it would allow you to document your approach.

```
//The text file babynames2004.txt is included. 

//Contains a list of the 1000 most popular names in the US. It is a space-delimited file of //1000 entries in which the rank is listed first, followed by the corresponding boy name //and girl name. 
const int Max_Name = 1000

//The most popular names are listed first and the least popular names are listed last. 
int rankArray[Max_Name];//a given index in all three corespondss to the row in the file
char boyArray[Max_Name][SomeConstantMaxLengthValue];
char girlArray[Max_Name][SomeConstantMaxLengthValue];

//write a program that allows the user to input a name. 
int main(unsigned int argc, const char** argv )
{
    std::cin >> searchName;

    //The program should then read from the file and search for a matching name among the   
    //girls and boys then store this information in an array. If a match is found, it 
    //should output the rank of the name. The program should also indicate if there is no 
    //match.
    if ( readNameFromFile( searchName , rank, girlName, boyName ) )
    {
        Store( rank,girlName,boyName );
        std::cout << .... //details retireved...
    }
    else
    {
         //Not found - do something helpful
    }
}
```

`readFromFile` and `Store` are the bits that do the work, think about *passing arguments by reference* (google/c++ textbook) *so that you can manipulate them* in your function. *See Ians hint about reading the file.*

your question only seems to want you to store the ones selected by the user, otherwise it wants you to **search the file** and pick out the correct line. True it is more efficient to read all and then store but that is your decision. If you do read everything, then you just need to move through the 2 name arrays until a name matches. then pull out the details from rank,girl, and boy arrays... *hint* `strncmp(...)` or possibly if you could use `std::string` for the names E.g.

```
std::string boyNames[Max_Name];
std::string girlNames[Max_Name];
```

it might be easier but I'm guessing you need to use `char`

The actual array needs to be chosen with care because the names are arbitrary lengths, so you might want to consider how to record the details - if it is going to be char arrays then you need to make sure of lengths when storing etc.... See how you get on and come back if there are any questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**

`ifstream` has a method called `getline` that allows you to specify what delimiting character you want.

Since boy names and girl names don't have any particular relationship to each other you could store them in completely separate lists, but what happens if there's a name that appears in *both* lists?

Each name comes with a rank, so that information does need to be stored in such a way that 2 pieces of data can be associated with eachother.

Comment: How would you calculate rank of the name in this case?

Comment: from the question "the rank is listed first, followed by the corresponding boy name and girl name". If you store the name along with the rank, or store the name in a way that indicates what the rank is (I'm trying not to give it away), then you can get it fairly easily